# glossaries, glspldesc or glsdescpls

Tags: glossaries

I am using `\glsdesc{XX}` to replace `\gls{XX}` when `XX` is used only once in my document.
How to replace `\glspl{XX}` when that is the only occurrence?
`\glspldesc` and `\glsdescpl` are not defined.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    nonumberlist,
    nogroupskip,
    nomain,
    acronym
    ]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\makenoidxglossaries

\newabbreviation
    {XX}{XX}{Some Long XX}
\setkeys{glslink}{hyper=false}

\begin{document}

\glspl{XX}

\glsdesc{XX}

%\glspldesc{XX} fails but should print XXs
%\glsdescpl{XX} fails but should print XXs

\printnoidxglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you're open to switching packages [`acro`](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) can detect single usage of an acronym and produce the long form from `\ac` (the `\gls` equivalent) without defining the acronym as it would otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the description but the long form, so use the associated long form commands which do have `*pl` alternatives as well as different capitalisations.

With [`glossaries-extra`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) this should be `\glsxtrlong`, or `\acl` with the `shortcuts=ac` package option.
With just [`glossaries`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) this would be `\glsentrylong` or `\acrlong`, or `\acl` with the `shortcuts=true` package option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    nonumberlist,
    nogroupskip,
    nomain,
    acronym
    ]{glossaries}
\usepackage[shortcuts=ac]{glossaries-extra}
\makenoidxglossaries

\newabbreviation
    {XX}{XX}{Some Long XX}
\setkeys{glslink}{hyper=false}

\begin{document}
\glspl{XX}

\glsdesc{XX}

\glsentrylong{XX}

\glsentrylongpl{XX}

\acrlong{XX} % Note the glossaries-extra warning

\acrlongpl{XX} % Note the glossaries-extra warning

\glsxtrlong{XX} % Requires glossaries-extra

\glsxtrlongpl{XX} % Requires glossaries-extra

\acl{XX} % Requires shortcuts package option

\aclp{XX} % Requires shortcuts package option

\printnoidxglossaries
\end{document}
```

> Some Long XXs (XXs)
>
> Some Long XX
>
> Some Long XX
>
> Some Long XXs
>
> Some Long XX
>
> Some Long XXs
>
> Some Long XX
>
> Some Long XXs
>
> Some Long XX
>
> Some Long XXs
>
> ### Acronyms
>
> XX Some Long XX.